# TextField input soft keyboard return button weird navigation on iOS 15

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios15

I have a TextField in my view for search product. When touch TextField - the soft keyboard appear and write text normally. When press the return button the keyboard disappear normally in **iOS 14** but when run on **iOS 15** device it weirdly navigate to other view. Does anyone face that problem?
My TextField code is:

```
TextField("Search product", text: $searchableText)
   .font(.system(size: 16))
   .padding([.top, .bottom])
   .keyboardType(.default)
```

and the logs are:

```
    2021-10-16 17:48:13.185299+0600 ExampleProject[640:155611] Unbalanced calls to begin/end 
    appearance transitions for <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerV8ExampleProject8CartView_: 
    0x11d65e820>.
    2021-10-16 17:48:13.283157+0600 ExampleProject[640:155611] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to 
    simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2820c9a40 'BIB_Trailing_CB_Leading' H: 
    [_UIModernBarButton:0x10df9d9b0]-(6)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x10dfb50c0'Back']   
    (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2820cb200 'CB_Trailing_Trailing' _. 
    UIModernBarButton:0x10dfb50c0'Back'.trailing <= 
    _UIButtonBarButton:0x10df2cb00.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2820d9900 'UINav_static_button_horiz_position' 
    _UIModernBarButton:0x10df9d9b0.leading == 
    UILayoutGuide:0x283a9b020'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2820d97c0 'UINavItemContentGuide-leading' H: 
    [_UIButtonBarButton:0x10df2cb00]-(6)- 
    [UILayoutGuide:0x283a988c0'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2820cb1b0 'UINavItemContentGuide-trailing' 
    UILayoutGuide:0x283a988c0'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide'.trailing == 
    _UINavigationBarContentView:0x10df80b80.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2820d0550 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' 
    _UINavigationBarContentView:0x10df80b80.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2820cb390 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(8)- 
    [UILayoutGuide:0x283a9b020'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: 
    '|':_UINavigationBarContentView:0x10df80b80 )>"
    )

    Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
    <NSLayoutConstraint:0x2820c9a40 'BIB_Trailing_CB_Leading' H: 
   [_UIModernBarButton:0x10df9d9b0]-(6)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x10dfb50c0'Back']   
   (active)>

   Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in 
   the debugger.
   The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in 
   <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
   2021-10-16 17:48:13.283738+0600 RSTWorld[640:155611] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to 
   simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2820c8c80 UIView:0x10df4ef40.trailing == 
    _UIBackButtonMaskView:0x10dfccf00.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2820dadf0 'Mask_Trailing_Trailing' 
    _UIBackButtonMaskView:0x10dfccf00.trailing == _UIButtonBarButton:0x10df2cb00.trailing   
    (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2820db160 'MaskEV_Leading_BIB_Trailing' H: 
    [_UIModernBarButton:0x10df9d9b0]-(0)-[UIView:0x10df4ef40]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2820d9900 'UINav_static_button_horiz_position' 
    _UIModernBarButton:0x10df9d9b0.leading == 
    UILayoutGuide:0x283a9b020'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2820d97c0 'UINavItemContentGuide-leading' H: 
    [_UIButtonBarButton:0x10df2cb00]-(6)- 
    [UILayoutGuide:0x283a988c0'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2820cb1b0 'UINavItemContentGuide-trailing' 
    UILayoutGuide:0x283a988c0'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide'.trailing == 
    _UINavigationBarContentView:0x10df80b80.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2820d0550 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' 
    _UINavigationBarContentView:0x10df80b80.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2820cb390 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(8)- 
    [UILayoutGuide:0x283a9b020'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: 
    '|':_UINavigationBarContentView:0x10df80b80 )>"
    )

     Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
     <NSLayoutConstraint:0x2820c8c80 UIView:0x10df4ef40.trailing == 
     _UIBackButtonMaskView:0x10dfccf00.trailing   (active)>

     Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this 
     in 
     the debugger.
    The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in 
    <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
    2021-10-16 17:48:13.284580+0600 RSTWorld[640:155611] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to 
    simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2820cb070 'BIB_Leading_Leading' H:|-(0)- 
    [_UIModernBarButton:0x10df9d9b0]   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x10df2cb00 
     )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2820d9900 'UINav_static_button_horiz_position' 
    _UIModernBarButton:0x10df9d9b0.leading == 
    UILayoutGuide:0x283a9b020'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2820d97c0 'UINavItemContentGuide-leading' H: 
    [_UIButtonBarButton:0x10df2cb00]-(6)- 
    [UILayoutGuide:0x283a988c0'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2820cb1b0 'UINavItemContentGuide-trailing' 
    UILayoutGuide:0x283a988c0'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide'.trailing == 
    _UINavigationBarContentView:0x10df80b80.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2820d0550 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' 
    _UINavigationBarContentView:0x10df80b80.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2820cb390 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(8)- 
    [UILayoutGuide:0x283a9b020'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: 
    '|':_UINavigationBarContentView:0x10df80b80 )>"
    )

    Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
    <NSLayoutConstraint:0x2820cb070 'BIB_Leading_Leading' H:|-(0)- 
    [_UIModernBarButton:0x10df9d9b0]   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x10df2cb00 
     )>

    Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in 
    the debugger.
    The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in 
     <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: As long as it is in the right place and works, you can ignore those types of errors.

Comment: But only works fine in ios 14, problem in ios 15.

Comment: How exactly, is it not working in iOS 15?

Comment: @Yrb thank you for your feedback. I solve that problem. This problem occur for TabView -> tabItem -> onAppear.

Comment: If you have a new question, you have to make a new post. However, consider posting your answer for the next person.